# Pass /MP option to the compiler using MSBuild

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a VC project file that I'm building from command line using MSBuild. I want to specify the `/MP` flag *without* editing the project file. Is that possible?
I've tried `set CL=/MP` prior to calling MSBuild, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be accomplished by accessing the `CL_MPCount` Visual Studio option:

```
MSBuild /m:2 /p:CL_MPCount=2 /p:Configuration=Release tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj
```

The above instructs the compiler to perform a maximum of 2 parallel compilation tasks. The `/m:2` flag allows `MSBuild` to build two projects in parallel. The net result is that we have a maximum of 4 `cl.exe` processes running in parallel.

**UPDATE:** The `CL_MPCount=2` flag gets passed on to `cl.exe` as `/MP2`. This allows parallel compilation of 2 `.cpp` files within the same project.

Comment: But that still will not allow MSBuild to compile a number of `.cpp` files from the same project in parallel, right?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes) the /MP2 flag allows files in the same project to be compiled in parallel. I'll update my answer to explain how the /MP comes about.

Comment: `/m:2` does the same as `/p:CL_MPCount=2` or they should be used both to take effect? 
And `/maxcpucount` does not replace it if we want to use all processor cores?

Comment: @HarpyWar The `/m:2` flag allows parallel **build** of _Project-1_ and _Project-2_ within a solution. The `/p:CL_MPCount=2` allows parallel **compile** of _Project-1/Source-1.cpp_ and _Project-1/Source-2.cpp_.

Comment: @KalenGi thanks for clarification. If I understand correctly /maxcpucount = /m without parameters, and it uses all cpu cores. How to use /p:CL_MPCount to utilize all available processor cores, without setting count of cores explicitly?

Comment: @HarpyWar There is a good explanation at [Parallel builds of clang on Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/checkedc-clang/wiki/Parallel-builds-of-clang-on-Windows). It is recommended that you pass **2 or 3** for  `/p:CL_MPCount` if you have at least **1GB per CPU core** and you are passing `/m` without parameters. Otherwise you'll end up with too many _cl.exe_ processes.

Answer (score 6):

You need a property that you can override from the command line.  Open the .vcxproj file in a text editor, Notepad will do.  Locate the "Globals" property group and add a property named, say, "Turbo"

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <Turbo>false</Turbo>
    ...etc...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And use the property to specify the compile option.  Since it can only work in the Release build:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>$(Turbo)</MultiProcessorCompilation>
        ...etc...
    </ClCompile>
```

And run MSBuild:

```
  msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Turbo=true
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it can only work in release mode"?

Comment: Just read the MSDN docs for /MP, it lists the cases where it cannot be used.

Comment: It works in any build configuration, that's all I know. So that remark is incorrect.

Comment: Well, don't let an "incorrect" remark slow you down, simply add the line to the Debug definition group as well.

Comment: Right, never mind. Sorry, I have worded my question incorrectly. It's not that I don't want to add `/MP` to the project file, I just don't want to edit it at all.