# CMake remove "Full Path of Source Code File in Diagnostics" option /FC

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

How can I instruct CMake in the CMakeLists.txt to create a Visual Studio project that does not contain the /FP [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s.aspx)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: This seems to be impossible, at the moment. You may file a bug report on the 
 [CMake Issue Tracker](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues).

---

The default setting for "Full Path of Source Code File in Diagnostics" seems to be set to enabled. In Visual Studio, if you open the project's properties and navigate to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced`, you will find the "Use Full Paths" property, which is enabled. You may also recognize that it is printed in a non-bold font, indicating a default value. Set it to "no" and it turns bold.

Saving the project will add a line to the `<project>.vcxproj` file:

```
[...]
<ClCompile>
    [...]
    <UseFullPaths>false</UseFullPaths>
</ClCompile>
[...]
```

Obviously, CMake needs to add this line to explicitly disable the compile flag. However, from [a search of the repository](https://gitlab.kitware.com/search?search=UseFullPaths&group_id=&project_id=541&search_code=true&repository_ref=master), we learn that there is currently no implementation to achieve this. The `FC` flag is mapped to nothing or to `true`:

```
[...]
{ "UseFullPaths", "FC", "", "true", 0 },
[...]
```

Remember, both ways indicate to turn on "Full Path of Source Code File in Diagnostics".

To Conclude: There is no implementation in CMake, which allows to explicitly disable this flag. You have to write a post process script to change the `<project>.vcxproj` file accordingly.

Comment: What about removing it directly from msbuild? Is that possible?

Comment: @user1618465 No, there is no option to set this flag. You'd need to [create a custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296182/579698), which again requires to edit the generated project file.

Comment: As reference: I did create an issue in CMake to address this problem: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18261